# configure smtp services in xampp

Tags: xampp, smtp, localhost

I'm trying to send a mail from the local host.I'm using xampp but every time i am getting the same error saying"HOST NOT FOUND" please help.

here is my php.ini file

```
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port=587
; For Win32 only.
http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = bajajsb08@gmail.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -
t").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path ="\"L:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra 
parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail().
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed 
by the filename
mail.add_x_header=off
```

here is my sendmail.ini

```
[sendmail]
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=auto
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=bajajsb08@gmail.com
auth_password=******
force_sender=bajajsb@gmail.com
hostname=smtp.gmail.com
```

here is debug.log

```
17/06/23 11:25:06 ** --- MESSAGE BEGIN ---
17/06/23 11:25:06 ** To: bajajsb08@gmail.com
17/06/23 11:25:06 ** Subject: Test email
17/06/23 11:25:06 ** From: bajajsb@gmail.com
17/06/23 11:25:06 ** Reply-To: bajajsb@gmail.com
17/06/23 11:25:06 ** 
17/06/23 11:25:06 ** Hello World!
17/06/23 11:25:06 ** 
17/06/23 11:25:06 ** This is my first mail.
17/06/23 11:25:06 ** --- MESSAGE END ---
17/06/23 11:25:07 ** Connecting to smtp.gmail.com:587
17/06/23 11:25:07 ** Disconnected.
17/06/23 11:25:07 ** Disconnected.
17/06/23 11:25:07 ** Disconnected.
17/06/23 11:25:07 ** Socket Error # 11001<EOL>Host not found.
```

here is basic mail script i am running:

```
<?php 
$to = 'bajajsb08@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Test email'; 
$message = "Hello World!\n\nThis is my first mail."; 
$headers = "From: bajajsb@gmail.com\r\nReply-To: bajajsb@gmail.com";
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
?>
```

Comment: If you have firewall that can block apache's internet connection. Bu sure that

Comment: Checked it no problem there.

Comment: Somebody help me please , my project is halted just because of this :(

Answer (score 0):

http://toknowtipsandtricks.blogspot.in/2012/12/smtp-configuration-in-xampp-server-to.html

you will find your answer here

Comment: I have tried it already but can't sort this host not found error:(